# Spring framework compatibility between various projects

Tags: spring, maven-2

I am learning Spring framework and while trying "various" sub-projects within this, I got this doubt.

Spring framework has **`"core spring"`** at the heart of it. Now, as the project grows, e.g. trying other features like: `spring-mvc, spring-web flow , spring security etc.` Are all those sub-projects part of same release. For example, if I look for spring 4.0.2 release, would all these sub-projects be included in this? (hence release for various sub-project with same number: 4.0.2).

If this is not correct, then how do we ensure to chose the compatible sub-projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-mvc` is part of the spring framework, the others are separate projects following their own versioning. In general there is a minimum version for the projects and most work fine with newer versions.

If you want to be sure use the [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) to manage your dependencies.

In your pom add

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you can simply add the dependencies (without version) to your dependencies section

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For a list of managed dependencies (and version) check [Appendix A](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) of the reference guide.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does this mean, with this approach, only compatible sub-projects would get downloaded? In your example, you have not specified the version, So which version would it download? Does this depend on the what is specified in <dependencyManagement> ?

Comment: That is specified in the platform pom. (I suggest reading the project info on that).

Answer (score 1):

> Spring framework has "core spring" at the heart of it. Now, as the
>   project grows, e.g. trying other features like: spring-mvc, spring-web
>   flow , spring security etc. Are all those sub-projects part of same
>   release

spring-mvc and spring-web are both individual artifacts that you'll find within a single Spring release. They are versioned together, and you should always use the same version for all of them in any given project.

spring-security, however, is a completely different beast. It sits on top of Spring, but it's versioned completely separately. You need to make sure that the version of Spring Security you use is combined with a compatible version of Spring.